# Disable a Field in Content Editor

Tags: sitecore-client

I have a DropLink Field which i want to disable(read only) for the content editor

I have tried setting permissions on the security field

[image]

The field is still editable to the content editor

[image]

Am i missing anything ?

Comment: Can you show how you set the security? Also, when checking, are you logged in as an editor or as admin? (Admin ignores security)

Comment: If you're logged in as an admin user, all permissions are disabled

Comment: am logged in as admin when i set the security and logged in as editor to check if it is disabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Field Write` access right on the field item:

[image]

Remember to set the access right on the role which shouldn't have access to that field. If you set `deny` on `sitecore\everyone` you will never be able to grant that access to any user from `sitecore` domain anymore (except from admin accounts).